# how to add a new repository outside graphdb.home

Tags: graphdb

I am cloning a large public triplestore for local development of a client app.

The data is too large to fit on the ssd partition where <graphdb.home>/data lives.  How can I create a new repository at a different location to host this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphDB on startup will read the value of `graphdb.home.data` parameter. By default it will point to `${graphdb.home}/data`. You have two options:

**Move all repositories to the big non-SSD partition**

You need to start graphdb with `./graphdb -Dgraphdb.home.data=/mnt/big-drive/` or edit the value of `graphdb.home.data` parameter in `${graphdb.home/conf/graphdb.properties`.

**Move a single repository to a different location**

GraphDB does not allow creating a repository if the directory already exists. The easiest way to work around this is to create a new empty repository `bigRepo`, initialize the repository by making at least a request to it, and then shutdown GraphDB. Then move the directory `$gdb.home/data/repositories/bigRepo/storage/` to your new big drive and create a symbolic link on the file system `ln -s /mnt/big-drive/ data/repositories/bigRepo/storage/`

You can apply the same technique also for moving only individual files.

Please make sure that all permissions are correctly set by using the same user to start GraphDB.